# Hubot with hipchat adapter not starting on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, bots, hubot

I'm not very well versed in nodejs, but I'm trying to install hubot and run it with the hipchat adapter but, I'm getting the following error, package.json below.

I've followed this tutorial, http://theprogrammingbutler.com/blog/archives/2011/10/28/hipchat-hubot-and-me/ and the official one in the hubot-hipchat repo, https://github.com/hipchat/hubot-hipchat - I even tried setting it up on heroku to no avail. I'd prefer to set it up on my ubuntu 12.04 ec2 instance though, but if someone has a surefire way to heroku it's no problem :) Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've set the following environment variables also.

```
HUBOT_HIPCHAT_JID=<Username>
HUBOT_HIPCHAT_NAME=<Room nickname>
HUBOT_HIPCHAT_PASSWORD=<Password you created for hubots user>
HUBOT_HIPCHAT_TOKEN=<Token from Group Admin and API>
```

Error:

```
Error: Argument error
  at new JID (/home/ubuntu/falcbot/node_modules/hubot-hipchat/node_modules/node-xmpp/lib/xmpp/jid.js:30:15)
  at new Connector (/home/ubuntu/falcbot/node_modules/hubot-hipchat/src/connector.coffee:64:31, <js>:42:13)
  at HipChat.run (/home/ubuntu/falcbot/node_modules/hubot-hipchat/src/hipchat.coffee:48:5, <js>:68:19)
  at Robot.run (/home/ubuntu/falcbot/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.coffee:389:5, <js>:351:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/falcbot/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot:124:8, <js>:141:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/falcbot/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot:5:1, <js>:144:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hosted-hubot",
  "version": "2.6.3",
  "author": "GitHub Inc.",
  "keywords": [
    "github",
    "hubot",
    "campfire",
    "bot"
  ],
  "description": "A simple helpful robot for your Company",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/github/hubot/raw/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/github/hubot.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hubot": "2.6.3",
    "hubot-scripts": "2.5.3",
    "hubot-hipchat": "2.5.1-4",
    "optparse": "1.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.8.x",
    "npm": ">= 1.1.x"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I forgot to export the variables. I am now not getting any errors when starting hubot with -a hipchat